# pfsense firewall/NAT rules for 2 different LAN where LAN2 has public facing server

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

I'm looking for a pfsense ruleset that allows a client on LAN1 192.168.3.10 to access a public server on LAN2 10.0.0.2. ports 60000 -60015 TCP/UDP. I otherwise wish to keep these LAN's isolated from each other.
Current WAN ruleset, working well from external WAN.
I have tried NAT reflection, I think it does not work as they are on separate LAN.
Any ideas how I can accomplish this?
It's weird as other services also running on LAN2 10.0.0.2, like a small webservice to configure the server in question run just fine and can be accessed from LAN1.
[WAN Ruleset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5P8r.png)

Network topology
[Current Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poJZn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have resolved this issue, I still think it's not the most elegant way, so any answers appreciated. This rule never worked though even after resetting state tables. I'd left the rule on, then a pfsense firewall reboot to move the firewall saw it working.
on LAN1

- Interface:LAN1 IPV4
- Protocol: TCP/UDP
- Source:LAN1 net  Destination:
- WAN net  Port Range: 60000 - 60015